# How do I split a string once?

Tags: c, string

I want to split a string into only two parts at the first space character. For example, I have a string "Hay Guys LOL" and when split, "Hay" should be in one variable, and "Guys LOL" in the other.

I have looked into functions like `strtok` - it works, but I would prefer not looping and then combining the strings.

Here is what I currently have (trying sscanf):

```
char test[32];
strcpy(test, "Hay Guys LOL\r\n");

// p1 should have "Hay", and p2 have "Guys LOL"?
char p1[16], p2[16];
sscanf(test, "%s %s\r\n", p1, p2);

printf("p1: %s\n", p1);
printf("p2: %s\n", p2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider whether you really want `"\r\n"` in your string rather than just `"\n"`.  C uses just `"\n"`to represent a line ending; it's converted to and from the system-specific line ending (typically `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`) on input and output to text streams.  It depends on what you're going to use the string for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it:

```
sscanf(test, "%s %[^\r\n]", p1, p2);
```

The first `%s` will only read the first string upto the first blankspace read "Hay". Next the scanset will read until a `'\r'` or `'\n'` is *not* found in the string (`^` in the `[]` inverts the set) . Therefore the `%[^\r\n]` will read the rest of the string into `p2`.

**UPDATE**

As @Adam Rosenfield told, to avoid buffer overflows you need to limit the numbers of characters put into `p1` and `p2` by `sscanf`. You specify the nos of characters like `%10[^\r\n]`  and `%10s`  . Because these numbers needs to be a part of the format string therefore you might want to make the format string dynamically before use.

```
char format_string[MAX];

sprintf (format_string, "%%%ds %%%d[^\\r\\n]", 10, 10);

sscanf (test, format_string, p1, p2);
```

Above the format string with the length limitation is made first and then it is used. Note the escape characters. `%%` is used to print a single `%` in the output and `\\` is used to print a single `\` in the output string.

Comment: Watch out for buffer overflows!  It would be better to use the format string `"%16s %16[^\r\n]"` in this case, if `p1` and `p2` are each 16 bytes long.

Comment: i am trying to accept the answer - says that I can do so in 50 seconds